# How to send Logs to Lambda Function in iOS App?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

Hello I have a iOS App and want to send my Logs to a Lambda Function. 
I have the ARN Name of the Lambda Function. Where do I have to put this ARN that the Logs getting send to the Lambda?

Many Thanks
Marc

Comment: Cam you please offer more information on what you tried/ some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `invoke` API in Lambda Invoker to specify the function name. You find the API details here:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSLambda/AWSLambdaInvoker.h#L225

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you should make your Lambda an API that your app can PUT/POST the logs to.

AWS just released a feature to allow Lambdas to be directly hooked against an ALB (No need for APIGW).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers/

There is no need for your App to know about AWS at all. It just needs a restful API to send data to.

Another alternative is to use Amazon Pinpoint SDK in your app and post custom events 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/integrate-events.html